# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError WebCenter Sites

Tags: java, oracle, webcenter-sites

good day.

I'm working on WebCenter sites 11.1.1.8 and contanis the patch

the problem is the next: i execute the command ./catalogmover.sh, when a html file is imported, not the import is finished and sends this error:

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /opt/weblogic/BEA1036/Oracle_WCS1/ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/ESAPI.properties
Found in 'user.home' directory: /home/weblogic/esapi/ESAPI.properties
Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /opt/weblogic/BEA1036/Oracle_WCS1/validation.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/validation.properties
Found in 'user.home' directory: /home/weblogic/esapi/validation.properties
Loaded 'validation.properties' properties file

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.newInstance(Ljava/net/URL;)Lnet/sf/ehcache/CacheManager;**



at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache._initCache(EhCacheObjectCache.java:761)
        at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache.start(EhCacheObjectCache.java:564)
        at COM.FutureTense.Cache.LinkedCacheProvider.<init>(LinkedCacheProvider.java:45)
        at COM.FutureTense.Cache.LinkedCacheProvider.<clinit>(LinkedCacheProvider.java:30)
        at COM.FutureTense.Common.ftDBTable.<clinit>(ftDBTable.java:376)
        at COM.FutureTense.Util.TableData.setTableType(TableData.java:446)
        at COM.FutureTense.Util.TableParser.ParseHTML(TableParser.java:189)
        at COM.FutureTense.Util.TableParser.Parse(TableParser.java:71)
        at COM.FutureTense.Apps.CatalogMoverEngine.ImportTable(CatalogMoverEngine.java:3281)
        at COM.FutureTense.Apps.CatalogMoverEngine.ImportCatalogAction(CatalogMoverEngine.java:1672)
        at COM.FutureTense.Apps.CatalogMoverEngine$ImportCatalogAction.actionPerformed(CatalogMoverEngine.java:1555)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6329)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6094)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2040)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4692)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2098)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4520)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4235)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4165)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2084)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4520)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:681)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:640)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:638)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:654)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:652)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:651)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I hope you can help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing out the ehcache files?  I'm on Tomcat rather than WebLogic, but I had a similar problem and fixed it by stopping the app server, deleting all the "temp" and "working" files", restart the service.